# Cannot import HTTPConnection from six.moves.http_client

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I'm having problems trying to do a basic import from six.moves.http_client.

I've updated six to the latest version available on pip:

```
$ pip show six
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: six
Version: 1.10.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

But when trying to import for instance the HTTPConnection from the http_client, it gives me an error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named http_client
```

But I do can import http_client from six.moves

```
>>> from six.moves import http_client
>>> http_client.responses
{200: 'OK', 201: 'Created', 202: 'Accepted', 203: 'Non-Authoritative Information', 204: 'No Content', 205: 'Reset Content', 206: 'Partial Content', 400: 'Bad Request', 401: 'Unauthorized', 402: 'Payment Required', 403: 'Forbidden', 404: 'Not Found', 405: 'Method Not Allowed', 406: 'Not Acceptable', 407: 'Proxy Authentication Required', 408: 'Request Timeout', 409: 'Conflict', 410: 'Gone', 411: 'Length Required', 412: 'Precondition Failed', 413: 'Request Entity Too Large', 414: 'Request-URI Too Long', 415: 'Unsupported Media Type', 416: 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable', 417: 'Expectation Failed', 100: 'Continue', 101: 'Switching Protocols', 300: 'Multiple Choices', 301: 'Moved Permanently', 302: 'Found', 303: 'See Other', 304: 'Not Modified', 305: 'Use Proxy', 306: '(Unused)', 307: 'Temporary Redirect', 500: 'Internal Server Error', 501: 'Not Implemented', 502: 'Bad Gateway', 503: 'Service Unavailable', 504: 'Gateway Timeout', 505: 'HTTP Version Not Supported'}
>>> http_client.HTTPConnection
<class httplib.HTTPConnection at 0x106de96d0>
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm totally missing here?

Answer (score 0):

six uses complicated import tricks to do its magic. You can look at the class _SixMetaPathImporter in its source code. There is no real package six.moves.http_client.