# How do I fix "Import 'file_name' couldn't be resolved by pylance" problem?

Tags: python, http, six

This is the code:

```
from .packages import six 
from .packages.six.moves.http_client import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection
from .packages.six.moves.http_client import HTTPException  # noqa: F401
```

And the problem *Import ".packages.six.moves.http_client" could not be resolved Pylance* is raised at line 2 & 3.

Similar post that I found on this website is: [Cannot import HTTPConnection from six.moves.http_client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169399/cannot-import-httpconnection-from-six-moves-http-client) however I couldn't follow along with the answer given there.

Edit:1 Furthermore, When I run the file,
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
is raised at line
`from .packages import six` in above code.

Edit:2 This webpage: https://techwithtech.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package/ clearly explains the **ImportError** mentioned in *Edit:1* but I am unable to fix it.
So What am I missing here?

The file structure of connection.py and six.py are underlined in the picture below.

[image: The files are underlined where as the code is wrapped in bracket]

Comment: Is that typing problem, or raise when execute app.

Comment: it's typing problem I guess, cause the line `.packages.six.moves.http_client` gets underlined/highlighted and also certain `ImportError ` is returned (read edited post) when I run it.

Comment: So if it's typing problems it depends to your IDE or Editor

Comment: If your editor is VS code you can `#type: ignore` in order to disable

Comment: Hello @Javohir I implemented your fix `#type: ignore` but was greeted with same ``ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" so I made few changes at line 12 to 14 (look at the picture above) by using this code : `from  urllib3.packages import six from .packages.six import HTTPConnection as _HTTPConnection from .packages.six import HTTPException  # noqa: F401` however,now I get this `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPConnection' from 'urllib3.packages.six'`